# "Rendered with sIFR 3, revision 436" appearing inline

Tags: flash, sifr

I'm in the process of upgrading a client site to rev. 436 from an older version of sIFR 3, and can't for the life of me get the export to work correctly. I'm getting the following message when I view the .swf in the page or locally (via file://):

> Rendered with sIFR 3, revision 436

However, if I view the file directly (e.g., http://localhost/path/to/font.swf), the message is:

> Movie (436) is incompatible with sifr.js (undefined). Use movie of undefined.

I'm not usually this sIFR-stupid. Any ideas on where I should look?

Comment: I should mention that I've exported the SWF a number of times, using the default Options.as file. Dropping the cochin.swf into place on the website works just fine, but for some reason my exports aren't working.

(Flash CS4, OS X 10.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Flash movie and the sIFR JavaScript code need to be of the same revision. In your case, the Flash movie is r436 and the JavaScript code is so old it doesn't even pass a version number.

If it did, you might have seen something like:

> Movie (436) is incompatible with sifr.js (419). Use movie of 419.

I guess this message could be a bit more clear, especially if there is no version number.

Comment: Unfortunately, the .swf and sifr.js are actually both from the 436 rev.

Comment: You sure it's not a caching issue? Ping me on IM / mail if you like.

Comment: Managed to fix it after exporting a bunch of times. Not sure what happened, but it managed to resolve itself somehow. *shrug*

Thanks for the help, Mark. Really appreciate it, as always.

Answer (score 0):

ok,
figured it out.
you must export with CS3 or below.
exporting from CS4 causes this error!
s